# YAML regex to use after a character

Tags: ansible, yaml

I have an ansible playbook that references some network addresses, cidr addresses, and datacenternames and clusternames in the form of variables:

```
netName: "100-10.10.100.0/24"
networkCidr: "10.10.100.0/24"
```

Is there a way to (regex) to create a variable and remove before `100-` and possibly after the `/24`?

```
datacenterName: "DC1"
clusterName: "DC1-TEST-GENERAL"
```

Is there a way to create a variable for just `DC1` and then populate the `ClusterName` with the `datacenterName-TEST-GENERAL` or maybe `datacenterName-Environment-General`? Maybe create an `environment` variable and reference that in a couple different spots?

Im trying to have less variables in my vars.yml and if I can just add some regex to the yml I could eliminate some.

EDIT:

Thanks for the replies, edited my initial post and added more to make it cleaner looking than a comment.

What Im trying to get is this essentially. Here's the network piece of the vmWare build code:

```
- name: "{{ netName }}"
   ip: "{{ hostLookup.ipv4addrs[0].ipv4addr }}"
   netmask: "{{ netMask }}"
   gateway: "{{ gateWay }}"
```

I have a task that gets the IP address from Infoblox, using nios and host lookup. Thats not the issue.

Here are my vars.

```
netName: "100-10.10.100.0/24"
networkCidr: "10.10.100.0/24"
netMask: "255.255.254.0"
```

I really just want to enter 1 variable for `netName` and have the `networkCidr` and `netMask` get pulled from that variable. I thought there was way to pull the CIDR and convert to subnet mask?

Answer (score 2):

Both of your issues can be resolved without using RegEx.

You can refer to other variables by using curly brackets (i.e. `{{ variable }}`).

In your example what you would be looking for is something like:

```yaml
networkCidr: "10.10.100.0/24"
netName: "100-{{ networkCidr }}"
datacenterName: "DC1"
clusterName: "{{ datacenterName }}-TEST-GENERAL"
```

If you wanted to you could further split up your CIDR by having a separate variable for the IP and subnet, depends on how you need it.

This approach *is preferred* over using RegEx in your tasks because it improves readability throughout the entire playbook instead of using a complex RegEx like a [positive lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).

Comment: Regarding the network cider and potential into to extract, see https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters_ipaddr.html#playbooks-filters-ipaddr